# Unable to detect Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor on my RPi 4 through ADS1115

Tags: pi-4, sensor, breadboard, adafruit

My RPi 4 does not read any values in from my capacitive soil moisture sensor. I have a breadboard for the wiring that I will attach a photo of, and I am running a test program (simpletest.py from the official Adafruit github) to detect values of each input pin on the ADS 1115 (A0-A3). the program results show something like this

```
|       0 |         1|         2 |         3 |
______________________________________________
|     4544|      4528|       4544|       4592|
```

where 0-3 are the input slots A0-A3 on the ADS1115 and so even though I have the sensor pin in A0, it is only detecting the default values, as it matches the 3 unused AX slots.
[image]

Comment: Are the header pins soldered to the ADS1115 or is it a push fit?

Comment: no solder, just push fit into the breadboard @joan

Comment: You need to solder.  It is highly unlikely to be making a proper electrical contact just pushing through.